# Is it possible to share RAML file via APIKIT Console?

Tags: mule, raml, apikit

We want not just to share the API console that is provided via apikit component in a Mule application, but also the raw RAML file so consumers can create their own clients based on the RAML. As far as I know, there is not user friendly way to download the published raw RAML file from within the APIKit console. I just found that one can point to the /api url and do a GET with "application/raml+yaml" content-type, but it is not user friendly enough. Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL to your console with ?raml on the end of the url.

http://myapp.cloudhub.io/api/v1/console?raml

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It didn't work for me. We are using Mule ESB on-premise. Do you know from which APIKIT version is this option available? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In at least Mule 4.3.0 (maybe earlier), you can append `?api` to the console URL, e.g.

`http://localhost:88/myproject/console/?api`